# convert the month number to date

Tags: php, datetime

I am working on a task where I need the user to provide exact number of months it will take them to complete a task and then i need to convert that number to an exact date, so lets suppose a user enters 6, this should give me a date 6 months from now.

I tried the following code looking at different examples on line but I have a feeling the following examples treats the `$monthNum` as the actual month of a year rather than what I need it to do.

```
$monthNum = 5;
$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));
echo $monthName;
```

I will really appreciate any assistance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Demo [here](http://ideone.com/SVln7H)

Pop in your month in the `modify()` method.

```
$monthNum = 6;

$date = new DateTime();

$date->modify(" +{$monthNum} month");

echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Outputs

`2015-05-14`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$time = new \DateTime('+5 months');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+5 months"));
```

Answer (score 0):

in php 5.4+

```
echo (new DateTime())->modify('+6 months')->format('d M Y');
```